# How to use Ace Editor in correct way with Vue?

Tags: vuejs2, browserify, ace-editor

A project I am working on requires me to include a code editor in the Website. The most recommended / popular editor is ACE editor. When going through some example codes, it was mentioned that ACE with browserify is a better way to go forward. But I don't understand the exact difference of using the ACE API and the browserify ACE package by **thlorenz**.

I tried out the example code given in the **Brace** repository (https://github.com/thlorenz/brace/tree/master/example) but unable to understand how to include it properly in **Vue**. For instance if I change the language based on user input, how to change the ACE mode.

Some Pens or JsFiddles demonstrating the use of Core ACE API with Vue would be really helpful. Also the reason for using browserify with ACE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ace-builds` npm package instead of brace similar to https://github.com/nightwing/ace-webpack-demo

```
var ace = require("ace-builds")
require("ace-builds/webpack-resolver");
```